# PHPExcel class wrong value for column

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel class to read the xls file and then trying to insert into the db. But when I displayed the highest index value of row and column, it shows an error result for column field. I have data up to index 'R', but the code shows $highestColumn=J and $highestColumnIndex=10. But the highest row index is correct. My code is given below:

```
<?php
$filename="test.xls";
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
if (!file_exists($filename))
{
    echo "Not Exist!";
}
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
{
    $worksheetTitle     = $worksheet->getTitle();
    $highestRow         = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // e.g. 10
    $highestColumn      = $worksheet->getHighestDataColumn(); // e.g 'F'
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    $nrColumns = ord($highestColumn) - 64;
    echo $highestColumn;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $highestColumnIndex;

?>
```

My xls file column index format is given below:

[image: image of excel column index]
Any Idea?

Comment: If you have multiple worksheets, please make sure that you are referring to the same worksheet you want.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I don't have multiple worksheet. I only have one worksheet